# Make CSRF middleware work in Django's 404 error pages

Tags: python, django, csrf, middleware

I put a login box alone with a keyword search box in 404.html in a Django project so in case a 404 error is raised, visitors get more options to jump to other parts.

But the CSRF middleware doesn't work in 404 error page with no csrf token rendered. I tried move 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to first of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py but did not work either.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: Have you put a csrf token tag on the 404 page and getting no token generated?

Comment: Your question is too open...what results are you getting? Have you tried everything on this page: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: he is getting a 'CSRF verification failed', the token does not generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is you should make [your own error handler](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) and generate the token manually with django.middleware.csrf.get_token()

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they've fixed this in Django http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14565

That said, it doesn't seem to be in the latest release, so I created a custom error view with the same contents as `'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'`, making the changes found in the ticket diff file.